IR2110 MOSFET Gate driver Issue
I am trying to build a dc-dc boost convertor with a 5V input. In the circuit, I am using a IR2110 gate driver to step up my 5V PWM (From Arduino UNO r3) to 15V PWM for my IRF530A N-MOSFET. The problem is that sometimes my arduino cannot deliver the voltage that is required, so it delivers around 140mV to LIN even my PWM pin is on 3 (which is fixed duty cycle for troubleshooting) and my LO seems to convert it appropriately to 15V pwm. But when the Arduino does deliver the appropriate voltage to LIN (around 4.7V), the LO shows around 0.4V output pwm for some reason. I have checked for shorts between the pins and there aren't any. I have also replaced my mosfet driver with a new one, but the problem persists. I currently don't have any access to power sources, so I am afraid I cannot test anything right now except for using the 5V from USB to Arduino. Is there any way to pinpoint what the problem is? I am not sure whether the problem lies with my MOSFET or my gate driver or the arduino.
This is the picture of my circuit:

This is the code for the PWM:
int previousLDRValue = 0;
int ldrThreshold = 50;
int smoothingStep = 5;

void setup() 
{
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(11, OUTPUT); 

  TCCR2A = _BV(COM2A1) | _BV(COM2B1) | _BV(WGM21) | _BV(WGM20);
  TCCR2B = _BV(CS00);

  OCR2A = 128;
  OCR2B = 240;
}

void loop() 
{
  int currentLDRValue = abs(1024-analogRead(A0));
  int difference = abs(currentLDRValue - previousLDRValue);
  
  if (difference < ldrThreshold) {
    OCR2A = map(currentLDRValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
  } 
  else {
    if (currentLDRValue > previousLDRValue) 
    {
      OCR2A = min(OCR2A + smoothingStep, 255);
    } 
    else 
    {
      OCR2A = max(OCR2A - smoothingStep, 0);
    }
  }

  previousLDRValue = currentLDRValue;
  delay(20);
}

Schematic (I used random LEDs):

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

5V is not enough for the Vin pin of the Arduino UNO. Unless you also have a USB cable connected, you need 7-12V on Vin to power it.

As Tom said in the comments, the Arduino Uno's VIN requires 7-12V for operation. It regulates this down to 5V internally, so it requires some voltage margin to produce a proper output voltage.
You should use a separate series resistor on each LED chain to ensure even brightness and current sharing. The I/V curve of each LED varies a bit due to production tolerances, so without a separate resistor to limit the current you'll end up with each chain pulling different amounts of current.
Since you're only using optical feedback, rather than electrical, and your inductor value is so large, it'll be difficult to make the control loop stable. During power-on I would expect the control loop to initially read the output brightness as too low, ramp the duty cycle up (pulling a lot of current through the MOSFET in the process), then slew back to a correct duty cycle once the brightness reaches the nominal value. However, by that point, the current through the inductor will likely still be quite high, resulting in a fair bit of overshoot. Since you don't have anything in place to clamp the output voltage, it may exceed the maximum safe operating voltage for your LEDs. A zener diode clamp may help, but your control loop code will still need to be carefully designed.
Parasitics are likely to be a problem with the board construction you're using here. The typical output rise and fall times (tr, tf) for the IR2110 are 25ns and 17ns respectively. With a 10Ω resistor on the gate, you're going to see 15V / 10Ω = 1.5Apk gate charge/discharge current. That's 60mA/ns on the rising edge, 90mA/ns on the falling edge. A rough back-of-the-napkin calculation on wire inductance, assuming conductor diameter between 0.5mm and 1mm diameter and lengths on the order of 5-10cm each, you're looking at 50-100nH of inductance per lead. Multiply the rate of change of current (dI/dt) by the inductance, and you get the instantaneous voltage drop across the wire (VL = L∙dI/dt), which may be as much as 9V.
These problems will be exacerbated by a lack of decoupling capacitance. The goal of a decoupling capacitor is to provide a low impedance current loop for high-frequency currents, bypassing the parasitic inductance of the upstream power delivery path. In your case your power delivery path has a huge amount of parasitic inductance due to the flying wire construction. This construction also has low mutual capacitance in the power path (unlike in a PCB where your power and ground planes form a distributed capacitance network) which makes it even more critical to have decoupling nearby.
As a bare minimum you should place a 1uF ceramic capacitor across Vdd/Vss and a 10uF ceramic capacitor between Vcc and COM, as physically close to the IR2110 IC as you can, with the leads kept short. I would also condense the circuit to move all the parts much closer to each other, keeping wire lengths as short as possible, paying particular attention to shorten the path from the IR2110 to the MOSFET gate and the loop formed by the MOSFET, diode, and output capacitor.

Alright, I will test it out tomorrow with the modifications. However, I still don't understand why the voltage on my LO pin is low even when my other inputs have the appropriate voltage. I am measuring the voltage directly from the pin, so parasitic inductance shouldn't be a problem, assuming the inputs are all fine. Could you clarify it a bit more?

What are you measuring the output voltage with? Since it's PWM, a multimeter won't give you a correct value - it'll give you a vague average voltage. With all the parasitics here the board will almost certainly be misbehaving, so you may have already cooked the MOSFET. Hard to know.

I measured it with a multimeter, so I should get an average voltage of around 14V of the fixed 94% duty cycle on pin 3, but that is not the case. I will try the circuit out with a new MOSFET as well, but even with a faulty MOSFET, the driver should still be functioning correctly at the pins I assume? Unless the problem is from the Arduino low Vin not providing a stable PWM voltage?

Really hard to know without hands-on analysis to be honest, particularly with the board construction obfuscating the validity of the layout. Getting an oscilloscope on it would be your best bet.
